# JPA getResultList - How to get value from the response?

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, entitymanager

I'm trying to get admin's username and password from the database but I can't get the value of the list.
Here is the code for getting everything from admin table:

```
    EntityManagerFactory emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("My-database");
    EntityManager em=emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    List<Admin> list=em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Admin a").getResultList();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
```

This is what my SQL-table looks like:
[MySQL-table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vI9E.png)

I have this kind of class for Admin also

```
package data;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Admin.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Admin a")
public class Admin implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private String username;

   private String password;

   public Admin() {
   }

   public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
   }

   public void setUsername(String username) {
       this.username = username;
   }

   public String getPassword() {
       return this.password;
   }

   public void setPassword(String password) {
       this.password = password;
   }
}
```

I have tried in many ways to print the list but I have always gotten [data.Admin@1c36eb44] as a result. I need to save the username and the password to variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just one way:

```
List<Admin> list = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Admin a", Admin.class).getResultList();
for (Admin admin : list) {
   String username = admin.getUsername();
   String password = admin.getPassword();
   System.out.println(username + ", " + password);
}
```